# Geth Light Node: RPC connection read error err=EOF

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, light-clients

I'm trying to implement a Light Node on a RPi4B, but I keep getting the following error, which is logged nonstop:

> nov 16 21:21:09 Bumblebee geth[1066]: DEBUG[11-16|21:21:09.477] RPC
> connection read error                err=EOF

I'm using door 30304 and it's open.

```
  listenAddr: "[::]:30304",
  name: "Geth/v1.13.5-stable-916d6a44/linux-arm64/go1.21.4",
  ports: {
    discovery: 0,
    listener: 30304
```

[image]

BUT it does log the following error from time to time as well:

> DEBUG[11-16|21:47:33.301] Read error
> err="accept tcp [::]:30304: use of closed network connection"